# JQuery Simple Form and Serialize Stopped Working

Tags: serialization

I don't know what happened.  Yesterday this was working on a larger script I had. So I tried breaking it down to the bare minimum and still doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <form>
   <textarea name="customer_type">1</textarea>
  </form>

  <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
   $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
   });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears not to be executing the function.  Again it worked fine yesterday in a larger script.  I ran it with Firefox using Firebug.  I even went back to the site where I got that function thinking I had some syntax error and re-pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're adding the `submit` button. Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/606wft3p/

Comment: Ok, that is crazy.  Take a look at: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/    It honestly worked yesterday without a Submit button. But hey, it's working now.   My original script was just taking form data so I could test an Ajax call quickly.  Must be the moon.  Anyway thanks.  Still strange one.

Comment: What is crazy? you're calling `.on("submit")`

Comment: if you want to serialize as the selections change, use `.on("change")` and another function to serialize the form as they're doing in the jquery api example

Comment: I meant it's crazy it was working without the submit button yesterday.  I just had to refresh the page.  But submit works better as I can run it easy.  Thanks again.